# Can you access the Dataset of a parent report in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, subreport

Is it possible for a subreport to access the dataset of its parent report?

Comment: No, only what you pass in as parameters. Having said that, if the dataset is small, you might be able to get away with passing it in as multi-value parameters.

Comment: @StevenWhite Thanks

Comment: You could make the Parent report's dataset a Shared Dataset and use the shared dataset in your sub.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use dataset of a report in other report, but you can create a shared dataset and use it in all reports in your server.